# falta una entrada para la tabla «» en la cláusula FROM - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Tengo estas 4 tablas:

Tabla 1: Personas:

- codigo_persona(PK)
- persona_cedula_identidad
- persona_apellido
- persona_nombre
- persona_sexo

Tabla 2: Bioquimicos:

- codigo_bioquimico(PK)
- codigo_persona (FK)
- bioquimico_profesion
- bioquimico_fecha_inicio
- bioquimico_hora_inicio
- bioquimico_habilitado

Tabla 3 Subespecialidades:

- codigo_subespecialidad(PK)
- subespecialidad_nombre
- subespecialidad_estado

Tabla 4 Equipos:

- codigo_equipo(PK)
- codigo_bioquimico(FK)
- codigo_subespecialidad(FK)
- equipo_nombre
- equipo_marca
- equipo_modelo
- equipo_numero_serie
- equipo_fecha_adquisicion
- equipo_proveedor
- equipo_integridad
- equipo_garantia
- equipo_observaciones
- equipo_foto
- equipo_estado

De estas 4 tablas deseo obtener a que subespecialidad corresponde cada equipo y quien es el bioquímico responsable de ese equipo. Para ello hice la siguiente la consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM equipos
INNER JOIN personas ON personas.codigo_persona = bioquimicos.codigo_persona
INNER JOIN subespecialidades ON subespecialidades.codigo_subespecialidad = equipos.codigo_subespecialidad;
```

Pero me sale el siguiente error:

> ERROR:  falta una entrada para la tabla «bioquimicos» en la cláusula FROM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

en donde tienes

```
    INNER JOIN personas ON personas.codigo_persona = bioquimicos.codigo_persona
```

estás diciendo primero que quieres un JOIN entre equipos y personas, pero en la condicion del join "ON" tienes la tabla personas y la tabla bioquimicos.

la solución sería algo así:

```
    SELECT * FROM equipos
    INNER JOIN bioquimicos ON equipos.codigo_bioquimico = bioquimicos.codigo_bioquimico
    INNER JOIN personas ON personas.codigo_persona = bioquimicos.codigo_persona
    INNER JOIN subespecialidades ON subespecialidades.codigo_subespecialidad = 
    equipos.codigo_subespecialidad;
```